# My database getting stored in /data/data/package-name/app_database/file__0/*.db in Android through Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sqlite

I am trying to store some data in a database which i create using phonegap like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " +    results.rows.item(i).data);
   }
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

But the database is not getting created..Instead it is saving it in /data/data/package-name/app_database/file__0/00000000000000001.db

I want to save the data in /data/data/package-name/database/Database.db

How to do it?

Comment: why you just dont use sharedpreferences ?

Comment: I am developing it with phonegap for the very reason that this code will be common for all mobile platform,which is possible through sqlite.... Thats why i am prefering sqlite

Comment: I dont understand how you create database, I'm just using "base = context.openOrCreateDatabase("db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);" and it always is in /data/data/package-name/database/db...

Comment: Yes thats a native way to create the database in Android.I am trying to create the database using Phonegap API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the directory in which the database is created unless you modify the PhoneGap source code. I guess a better question is why do you want to save the data in /data/data/package-name/database/Database.db instead of /data/data/package-name/app_database/file__0/00000000000000001.db?

**Update**: Now that I understand the requirement better the only way you are going to be able to do this is to [write a plugin for Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) that interfaces the JavaScript side to the native Java side. Then you can open and read the DB in Java that your Service has created and populated.

Marc Murphy (CommonsWare) goes over the why in this [thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/177067).

Comment: Hi Simon,Thanks for the reply....Actually I have a service which runs in background and fills the /data/data/package-name/database/Database.db database with some values. Now from phonegap side,i want to read this database values and modify it...

Comment: Since KitKat the DB file is now in `/data/data/<your app package name>/app_webview/databases/file__0/1`

Answer (score 0):

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db and http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite. When creating the database, you can specify the database name and a file name with .db will be created in /data/data/package name/databases/.

Sorry, but the code you have provided doesn't show how the database has been created.

Comment: I have created the database using Phonegap API like this window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use LocalStorage instread of sqlite for this purpose.
 You can refer to Local storage at : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

**Example** :

```
localStorage.setItem("ItemName",yourItem);

localStorage.getItem("ItemName");
```

It provides a better way to store and retrieve your data easily and effectively

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) states, Phonegap doesn't really use a SQLite database, but a WebSQL implementation or localStorage.

If you want to use native SQLite, have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin), the syntax for database operations are nearly the same as for the Storage API of Phonegap.